# Failing to replace a document inside a JSONStore collection

Tags: javascript, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I'm developing a Cordova application (with MobileFirst Foundation 8.0) that uses JSONStore, as well as AngularJS.

The following function updates a document that is already stored in local collection 'agenda'.

```
update : function(element){

var defer = $.Deferred();

// set query for get document stored in local collection
var query = {id: element.id};

// search for exact value
var options = {
    exact: true,
    limit: 1
};

var collection = WL.JSONStore.get('agenda');

// invoke search function
collection.find(query, options)//WL.JSONStore.get('agenda').find(query, options)
.then(function (results) {
    // handle success - results (array of documents found)

    var rowstatus = results[0].json.rowstatus || '';

    // substitute current saved document with the update document
    results[0].json = element;

    // set value of rowstatus flag
    results[0].json.rowstatus = rowstatus===''?'UPD':rowstatus;

    var arrayMod = [];
    arrayMod.push(results[0]);

    //invoke replace procedure for update document in local collection
    collection.replace(arrayMod, {markDirty: false })//WL.JSONStore.get('agenda').replace(item, {markDirty: false})
        .then(function(docsRefreshed){

            console.log("docsRefreshed", docsRefreshed);

            defer.resolve();
        })
        .fail(function(refreshErr){

            defer.reject(refreshErr);
        });

})
.fail(function (findError) {

    defer.reject(findError);
});

return defer.promise();

}
```

The steps are:

1. find the document inside local collection by element's id - IT WORKS
2. update the content of document by replacing the object contained into 'json' property: the id doesn't change, I verified it - IT WORKS
3. replace the document inside the collection - IT FAILS

the error returned is not a standard error intercept by fail handler, it is the following:

> VM404 worklight.js:5139 Uncaught Exception: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at (compiled_code):57__log @ VM404 worklight.js:5139PUBLIC_API.(anonymous function) @ VM404 worklight.js:5539WL.Logger.window.onerror @ VM404 worklight.js:5497
>   VM404 worklight.js:57 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…)it @ VM404 worklight.js:57__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1951__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1947__handleJsonObj @ VM416 jsonstore.js:1942__handleJsonObj ....

[image]

Comment: This error usually means that you are calling a function over and over again and hitting the browser memory cap. How are you using this function? There are some good stackoverflow posts out there talking about this issue cropping up with recursion, when attaching an onClick handler to a lot of events, and a few other instances. Your actual update code looks correct, so I think we need to see more of your code.

Comment: @enrico.visentini I tried the same scenario with the json store sample from here https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/jsonstore/cordova/ and it works fine without any errors.

Comment: I tried to modify only a single property of 'json' element of document and it works. It means that I can't replace the entire 'json' object with the updated one (`results[0].json = element;`) because it causes this error. But why?

Comment: I resolve the issue. The error was caused by a property added automatically from the plugin that is used that causes the circular reference of the json object. Removing this attribute I can replace all the 'json' object.

Comment: Great, glad it works. Cheers

Comment: @enrico.visentini: Please write a detailed answer to the question instead of a comment, so others could benefit.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments by @encrico.visentini:

> I resolve the issue. The error was caused by a property added automatically from the plugin that is used that causes the circular reference of the json object. Removing this attribute I can replace all the 'json' object.